# Update query php fatal errors

Tags: php

i have some problem in my script.

i want to make update query in my program but i have some errors in my script.
i found the fatal erros in line 29.

somebody can give me suggestion?

my code :

```
<?php 

include("db.php");

$kd=$_POST['kd'];
$ins=$_POST['ins'];
$desc=$_POST['desc'];
$sn=$_POST['sn'];
$flo=$_POST['flo'];
$to=$_POST['to'];
$usd=$_POST['usd'];
$sat=$_POST['sat'];
$rdy=$_POST['rdy'];
$stat=$_POST['stat'];
$rmk=$_POST['rmk'];

//kode upload
$lokasi_file = $_FILES['nama_file']['tmp_name'];
$nama_file = $_FILES['nama_file']['name'];
$tipe_file = $_FILES['nama_file']['type'];

//kode untuk mengganti spasi menjadi garis bawah pada nama file
$nama_baru = preg_replace("/\s+/", "_", $nama_file);
$direktori = "images/$nama_baru";

//code untuk mengkopi file ke fodler foto
move_uploaded_file($lokasi_file, $direktori);

$sql("UPDATE consumable SET ins='$ins', part='$desc', serial='$sn' flow='$flo', time='$to', used_qty='$usd', ready_qty='$rdy', unit='$sat', status='$stat', remark='$rmk', foto='$nama_baru' WHERE no='$kd'"); <--- in this line i got Fatal error: Function name must be a string in.  

header("location: home.php");

?>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to count the lines and also guess what the error was?

Comment: please, we don't want to count your code and look for line 29 :), please comment problematic place like: `// <--- here error`

Comment: The error is on line which starts with `$sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a comma missing in update query part:

```
part='$desc', serial='$sn' flow='$flo',.. // change to

part='$desc', serial='$sn', flow='$flo',...
```

BTW if you are using mysql_ functions , Use of this `mysql_` is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: How do you know he's using `mysql_`? We can't see what `$sql` is set to.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`mysql_query("UPDATE consumable SET ins='$ins', part='$desc', serial='$sn' flow='$flo', time='$to', used_qty='$usd', ready_qty='$rdy', unit='$sat', status='$stat', remark='$rmk', foto='$nama_baru' WHERE no='$kd'");`

Instead of $sql.Because there no function called $sql to execute query

Comment: there is no showing errors but my program still cannot do the update function. can u help me?